# How to access elements of nested list(or array) in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I know following 2 methods:

Code:

```
mylist = [{'outer':[{'inner':[1,2,3]}, {'inner':[4,5,6,7]}]} ,
      {'outer':[{'inner':[11,22,33]}, {'inner':[44,55,66,77]}]}
     ]
```

the above list is example of my original code where i am dumping information in JSON format and also loading it. so "mylist" is the loaded json file.

1st method

```
for c in mylist: 
    for d in c['outer']:
        for e in d['inner']:
             print e
```

2nd method

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for j in range(len(mylist[i]['outer'])):
        for k in range(len(mylist[i]['outer'][j]['inner'])):
            print mylist[i]['outer'][j]['inner'][k]
```

What are the differences between above 2 methods for accessing elements of nested lists(or arrays) ?

And what are the technical differences between them?

Is there any better way other than above methods ?

Comment: Ease? Isn't the first method the clear winner here? Look at the number of words you had to type in the second method. And for timing use the `timeit` module, anyways accessing items by index is not the Pythonic way.

Comment: The second way is not Pythonic at all, consider this as an alternative: `[i['inner'] for i in z['outer'] for z in mylist]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary FYI I checked time of execution using timeit module and the 1st method takes more time than 2nd method.

Comment: @user3291873 Then why are you asking about timing difference in your question?

Comment: HI @Petrick. Your questions are really interesting - but you've asked too many questions for it to really count as A Question. Also the final question is a bit opinion-based... and Stack Overflow works best with specific, technical questions, rather than ones that ask for opinions... it might be best to avoid that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

use [nest list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) :

```
In [48]: print [e for c in mylist for d in c['outer'] for e in d['inner']]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]
```

it should be shorter and a bit faster (by printing the whole stuff one time).

Answer (score 0):

You can create function to flatten your input list like this:

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(l):
    for element in l:
        if isinstance(element, Iterable) and not isinstance(element, basestring):
            if isinstance(element, dict):
                element = element.values()
            for i in flatten(element):
                yield i
        else:   
            yield element
```

using your input:

```
In [3]: [ item for item in flatten(mylist) ]
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]
```

It works even for more nested lists like:

```
mylist = [ {'outer':
                { 'inner':
                    { 'inner-1': 1, 'inner-1-1': 11},
                  'inner2':
                    [ set((1,2,3,4)), tuple((5,6,7,8)), [9,10,11] ],
            }}]

In [3]: [ item for item in flatten(mylist) ]
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 11]
```